# fitting two parallel lines to two clusters of points

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem where I have two clusters of 3D points and I am trying to find the two parallel lines that are a given distance $d$ (i.e $d$ is not a variable) apart that will be a best fit for the two clusters in the least squares sense.  Currently I can find the best fit least squares line for each cluster independently using Principle Component Analysis.  How would I change the least squares formulation to adapt to my problem??

Thank you,

Mustafa

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a generalization of the [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform), somehow adapted to detect "parallel lines exactly d apart" rather than the more common "straight lines" detection or "circles" detection.